# double inAppPurchase when logged in with TestUserAcoount

Tags: in-app-purchase, sprite-kit

when i´m logged in with my testUserAcount, my inAppPurchases runs twice the buyAction. why is that? when my testUserAccount is not logged in, the buy action runs correctly:

```
-(void)fetchProducts{

NSLog(@"fetchProdukts");

SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithArray:self.products]];
request.delegate = (id)self;
[request start];}


-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest*)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{

self.products = response.products;}

-(void)request:(SKRequest *) request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

NSLog(@"%@", error);}

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{

for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {

    //PURCHASED
    switch (transaction.transactionState) {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:transaction];



            if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"StarMultiplier1"]) {
                 NSLog(@"Multiplier unlocked");
                [self buyMultiplierAction];


            }

            if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"add15000Stars3"]) {
                NSLog(@"Stars buyed");
                [self buyStarsAction];


            }

            if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"unlockArtefacts3"]) {
                NSLog(@"Artefacts unlocked");
                [self buyArtefactsAction];


            }

            if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"addPowerUps4"]) {
                NSLog(@"PowerUps buyed");
                [self buyPowerUpsAction];


            }



            break;


            //NOT PURCHASED
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:transaction];

                NSLog(@"Error: %@", transaction.error);
```

(when logged in)
for every action i get the logs twice. my code is correct.
???

Comment: What do you mean by logged in? I think you are not supposed to explicitly sign into test accounts in Settings.

Comment: i meant if i´m logged in with a testUserAccount. when i was not logged in with a testUser Account, Gamecenter let me not sign in as a localPlayer